# Unable to load Popup - Please try again later

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I can't write comments.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was no issue with the comment system. Instead, there was a bug on the *bounty system*, and the error message "Unable to load popup - please try again" appeared when "start a bounty" was clicked.

The bug should have been fixed, as per [Eeeek! Can't start a bounty on any question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320693) on Meta SE.

> Thanks for reporting this. It has been fixed across the network now and you should be able to add bounties until your heart is content.
>
> Thanks to [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) who smashed the bug very quickly.